# sql server 2008 r2 update max(recent) date in a table

Tags: sql, database

I have this table

[image]

I want to update the max (recent) endDate for orderId = 12.

I tried like this

```
UPDATE Order_Status
    SET endTime = @startTime
    WHERE @orderID IN (
    SELECT OrderID
    FROM Order_Status
    GROUP BY @OrderID
    Having max (@startDate)
```

but this doesn't even complied, please what is the right? thanks

EDIT
Sorry , I asked wrong, what I want is to update the end in the Most RECENT(starteTime)

I mean . what I want is to update the endTime value in the row which has the most recent StartTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
;with T as(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by StartTime desc) RNum from Order_Status where OrderID=12
)
update top(1) T set endTime=@startTime
```

for multiple OrderID, try

```
;with T as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by OrderID order by StartTime desc) RNum from Order_Status
)
update T set endTime=@startTime where RNum=1
```

Comment: what was that? is it sql ?

Comment: your first code update my old date, I want my most recenet data which means most max date

Comment: please I asked wrong, check my edit. what I want is to update the endTime value in the row which has the most recent StartTime